# Why getting Intelligence error in VS 2019

Tags: visual-studio, .net-framework-version, .net-4.8

First, I update the VS 2019. After that I updated my project from .net framework 4.6 to 4.8.

Now I getting the **Intelligence error** in the MVC view. I check some article and blog related it and try below points for it.

1. Delete the bin and obj folder.
2. Delete .vs file
3. Delete the packages folder.

I did all things but still I am getting the same Intelligence error.

Comment: WHAT errors do you get?

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same error after the framework upgrade. Need to add System.Core reference in the main Web.config file.

```
<compilation>
  <assemblies>
    <add assembly="System.Core, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
  </assemblies>
</compilation>
```